# what is the most appropriate circumstances to use try/catch in selenium-java-testng automation

Tags: java, exception

We can use try/catch block to catch exceptions while running test scripts.
However, in which conditions and layers (test, page object layer, framework layer) should we use try-catch block, please?. also the best practices using try/catch block, please?.

Comment: please find the below link  https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/exception-handling-framework-selenium-tutorial-19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general using try/catch block makes your execution slower.
Use the try/catch block when you are unsure the code may give exceptions.

Such as whether the browser is up and running or not. whether I have premissions to do something or not

The general pitfall that some developers do is that they user try/catch for things they know the situation. In those cases its better to validate it with "if" conditions or proper validations.

conclusion: 
Use try catch only if you don't know the output of it
don't use when you can check the validation using an if or switch case